# Калькулятор систем счисления С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Преподаватель дал задание написать программу, которая будет переводить число из одной системы счисления в другую, у самого не особо выходит. В интернете откопал пару программ, которые некорректно работают, или с очень большим кодом, хотя я уверен, что код можно было бы написать намного короче, может завалялась у кого-то такая программа? Или кому-то не сложно написать? Желательно на windows forms

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/947277/222542) я уже вам давал ссылку на подобную программу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Индекс выходить за границы массивы С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947277/%d0%98%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public int GetValue()
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        return i;
    }


        int i = GetValue();
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(i, 8);
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(i, 16);
```

Вы это подразумевали?